# Centering table content

Tags: html

I am having hard times formatting a table.

I want column 2 to be centered and all the pictures and text to be one under another. I tried everything but they are not properly aligned. Please for some help.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr style="background-color: #08568a;">
                    <td style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #ffffff;">Date</span></td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #ffffff;">Some text</span></td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #ffffff;">Some text</span></td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;"><span class="number" style="color: #ffffff;">№</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="background-color: #e6f1ff;">
                    <td style="text-align: center;"> 19:00 Text
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;"> Name lenght 1 <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-13676" src="IMG URL" alt="ALT TEXT" width="24" height="24" />-:- <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-13677" src="IMG URL" alt="ALT TEXT" width="24" height="24" /> Name lenght 2 </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;"> Some text</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;"> 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="background-color: #e6f1ff;">
                    <td style="text-align: center;"> 22:00 Text
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;"> Name Lenght 3 <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-13673" src="IMG URL" alt="ALT TEXT" width="24" height="24" /> -:- <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-13675" src="IMG URL" alt="ALT TEXT" width="24" height="24" /> Name Lenght 4</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;"> Some text</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;"> 4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="background-color: #e6f1ff;">
                    <td style="text-align: center;"> 16:00 Text </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;"> Name Lenght 5 <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-13675" src="IMG URL" alt="ALT TEXT" width="24" height="24" /> -:- <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-13677" src="IMG URL" alt="ALT TEXT" width="24" height="24" /> Name lenght 6</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;"> Some text</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;"> 13</td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="background-color: #e6f1ff;">
                    <td style="text-align: center;"> 16:00 Text </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;"> Name lenght 7 <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-13673" src="IMG URL" alt="ALT TEXT" width="24" height="24" /> -:- <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-13676" src="IMG URL" alt="ALT TEXT" width="24" height="24" />Name lenght 8</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;"> Some text</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;"> 16</td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="background-color: #e6f1ff;">
                    <td style="text-align: center;"> 22:00 Text </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;"> Name lenght 9 <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-13675" src="IMG URL" alt="ALT TEXT" width="24" height="24" /> -:- <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-13676" src="IMG URL" alt="ALT TEXT" width="24" height="24" /> Name lenght 10</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;"> Some text</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;"> 27</td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="background-color: #e6f1ff;">
                    <td style="text-align: center;"> 22:00 Text
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;"> Name lenght 11 <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-13677" src="IMG URL" alt="ALT TEXT" width="24" height="24" /> -:- <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-13673" src="IMG URL" alt="ALT TEXT" width="24" height="24" /> Name lenght 12</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;"> Some text</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;"> 28</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are CSS methods for creating tables and accomplishing the commands. However, at times one wants a purely in-line HTML method to create a table, and the provided code offers suggestions.

One method in which centering can be accomplished is through the align tag. The align command in the table tag centers the table on the page, and "left" or "right" would change the placement as well.

TR align="center" will justify text in the row. Or text could be centered individually using TH / TD tags (center, left, right).

Standalone div commands could be used as well.

TH tags are optional heading rows. Background color can be set at the TH level, in any row or cell, and in the table tag itself. 'transparent' is a safe color to ensure use of the page's background color.

Column width can be set in TH and TD cells using percents or fixed values such as pixels.

There are a few ways to place images/captions on separate lines:

~ The laziest is to use the BR tag, which creates a line break and is comparable to Shift-Enter keyboard. BR has its place in coding but should not be overused. Adjust image padding in the img style tag to create buffer space for the caption text. (Row 15:00)

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp

One could alternately use 'p' or 'h' tags around the text; they define text styling and create new lines (roughly comparable to Enter keyboard).

~ A recommended approach is to use a small table within the cell that contains separate rows for image and caption. Image padding and table cell padding & spacing can be adjusted accordingly. (Row 16:00)

~ Or combine the two methods to create rows for image1 +'br' caption1, and image2 +'br' caption2. Image padding and table cell padding & spacing can be adjusted accordingly. (Row 17:00)

Table borders have been applied for ease of viewing.

Fonts have been set within the larger table as an example; however they could be defined easily in the stylesheet and implemented using a variety of command tags.

Hope this helps!

```
<table width="70%" align="center" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#000000" bgcolor="transparent">

<tr align="center" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<th width="25%" style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:14pt;">Date</div></th>
<th width="25%" style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:14pt;">Some text</div></th>
<th width="25%" style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:14pt;">Some text</div></th>
<th width="25%" style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:14pt;">No</div></th>
</tr>

<tr align="center">

  <td width="25%" style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:14pt;"><span class="style1" style="text-align: center;">15:00 Text </span></td>
  <td style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:14pt;"><span style="text-align: center;">Name Length 1<br> 
    <img src="IMG URL" alt="ALT TEXT" width="24" height="24" style="padding:10px"/> <br>
    -:-<br> 
    <img src="IMG URL" alt="ALT TEXT" width="24" height="24"  style="padding:10px"/> <br>
Name Length 2</span></td>
  <td style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:14pt;">Text</td>
  <td style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:14pt;">001</td>

  </tr>

  <tr align="center">

  <td style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:14pt;">16:00 Text</td>
  <td style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:14pt;">

    <table width="95%" align="center" border="1" border-color="000000" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td align="center">Name Length 5 
    <br>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center"><img src="IMG URL" alt="ALT TEXT" width="24" height="24" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">-:-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center"><img src="IMG URL" alt="ALT TEXT" width="24" height="24" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">Name Length 6</td>
    </tr>
   </table>

  <td style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:14pt;">Text here</td>
  <td style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:14pt;">002</td>
  </tr>

  <tr align="center">

  <td width="25%" style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:14pt;">17:00 Text</td>

  <td style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:14pt;">

    <table width="95%" align="center" border="1" border-color="000000" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">    
    <tr>
        <td align="center">Name Length 1<br>
          <img src="IMG URL" alt="ALT TEXT" width="24" height="24" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center">-:-</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center"><img src="IMG URL" alt="ALT TEXT" width="24" height="24" /> <br>
      Name Length 2</td>
  </tr>
    </table>    

  <td style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:14pt;">Text here</td>
  <td style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:14pt;">003</td>
  </tr>

  </table>


<div align="center"> Div align="center" can be used as a stand-alone command to center elements.</div>
<div align="left"> Use div align="left" to justify to the left.</div>
<div align="right"> Use div align="right" to justify to the right.</div>
```